# Error checkout woocommerce, el campo región no se despliega

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

En un woocommerce cuando el usuario llega a la página de checkout tiene que seleccionar una región a través de un campo "select". **No obstante (el fallo) woocommerce no se porque pone un campo de tipo "text"** Sin embargo si hacemos un reload el problema se corrige y aparece el "select" con todas las opciones. Otro dato curioso es que la primera vez pone en la label “Región / Provincia” y después del reload solo “Región”.

Ya hemos probado lo habitual y descartamos que sea por la versión
de Wordpress o Woocommerce o por la versión de Php que usamos. También hicimos limpieza de plugins.

Answer (score 0):

hace unos meses nos encontramos con el mismo error (exactamente el mismo).
Buscando por internet encontramos que poniendo un código en el css personalizado se solventaba. Prueba y nos comentas si te ha funcionado.

```
.woocommerce form .form-row select.state_select {
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}
```